# Is there a continuous extention at $(0,0)$ $f(x,y)= \frac{x^{2021} *e^y}{1+x-e^y}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

$$f(x,y)= \frac{x^{2021} *e^y}{1+x-e^y}$$

i said that domain is {$(x,y) \in R^2 : x+e^y \neq -1$}

I tried to show that yes then no but i did not succeed

Comment: "I tried to show that yes then no but i did not succeed" What does this mean?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Firstly i tried to show that there is a continuous extension but I stucked , then i tried to show that there isn't

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|f(\frac 1  n , \ln (1+\frac1  n+\frac 1 {n^{2022}})| \to \infty$ as $ n \to \infty$.

Comment: thank you for your help